# Nginx ingress - (Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to expose my deployment on my Kubernetes cluster using a service and a Nginx ingress. I currently have following configuration.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mira-api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mira-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mira-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: registry.gitlab.com/izit/mira-backend
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
              protocol: TCP

--- 

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mira-api-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: mira-api
  type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mira-api-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - kubernetes.mira-appservice.be
      secretName: mirasecret
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes.mira-appservice.be
      http:
          paths:
            - backend:
                serviceName: mira-api-service
                servicePort: 8080
```

This configuration makes my deployment publically available over HTTPS with the correct certificate etc.
The only problem is that I receive a HTTP 502 error message when making a request.
When I check the logs of the ingress is see following error message:
[image]

When I describe the ingress I get the following information:
[image]

Is the configuration of my service correct? Or is there something else missing in the configuration?

---

### UPDATE

Output for service:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check if your ` mira-api-deployment` pod is running or not.

Comment: The pod is running.

Comment: Please share the output for `kubectl get svc mira-api-service`

Comment: Your yaml files are looking good. I've tested it and it works using a different container. What kind and version of controller you are using. How did you set-up our controller (please provide links to the online resources). Please send output for `kubectl get pods`. Also check if your application is working accessing it directly in the pod using another pod (busybox for example) from inside kubernetes network. If it works, try to remove tls from your ingress setup and check how it goes.

Comment: due to other issues like: ingress Address: #empty#, Path #empty#, missing information about health checks for backends, missing important information from `kubectl describe ingress`: (at the bottom). Please provide more details as stated by  [mWatney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684634/nginx-ingress-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream#comment105641356_59684634)